# Как использовать ipv6 на Mikrotik c МТС свистком?

Tags: mikrotik, ipv6

Доброе время суток. Тут узнал, что у МТС есть услуга "Доступ к IPv6". Активировал. В самом микротике включил пакет ipv6. Как теперь заставить это работать?) Мне нужно создать DHCPv6 клиент с интерфейсом на WAN, что в моем случае ppp соединение, правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Во первых нужно убедиться в правильной инициализации. Нужно смотреть дебаг. Пока убери строку с apn и добавь строку инициализации, где в my.apn поставь свой апн

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IPV4V6","my.apn"
```

У микротика плохая поддержка NDIS. Потому DHCPv6 клиент ставить некуда в Вашем случае. Если ppp согласует ipv6 - Вам повезло.

Если нет, то нужен модем который определится как lte, при том если модем прошит вэб интерфейсом то эта прошивка натит и не факт что передаст ipv6.

В лучшем случае нужен lte интерфейс с прямым NDIS, а не RNDIS. Тогда его можно проинициализировать с `AT+CGDCONT=1,"IPV4V6","my.apn"` и повесить dhcp6client. Такие модемы я встречал только производства микротик. На Хуавэях я пробовал переключить режим в NDIS, но микротик всеравно звонит в PPP.

В 7ой версии будут новые драйвера - возможно чтио-то получится.

Comment: Модем e3372h как lte интерфейс. Прошивка: 22.333.01.00.00 веб морда: 17.100.13.112.03. На микротик RouterOS: 6.45.7 Модем показывает IPv6 WAN: 2a00:1fa2:8484:4de7:b8ab:beff:fe34:0000. На микротик в IPv6 address вижу адрес lte интерфейса только уже fe80::e5b:8fff:fe27:9a64/64. Passthrough Interface не работает, соединение сразу падает, я так понял, потому что два dhcp сервера, один на модеме, другой на роутере. На 4pda всю ветку уже прочитал ipv6 в мтс, но маглам походу это не по силам.)

Comment: тоже с ним пробовал. микротик не видит ндис

Comment: как не видит? Я же вижу fe80::e5b:8fff:fe27:9a64/64 адрес который выдает dhcp сервер на модеме.

Comment: а, морда, это rndis. fe80::e5b:8fff:fe27:9a64 - это локальный адрес по типу 192.168.0.0. дхчп вообще не причем.

Comment: Ну трафик то идет. По ipv4 работает, я не понимаю причем ndis